# Vertical alignment bug with number input in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, input, numbers

Number inputs in Chrome act really weird with respect to vertical alignment of their content.

I'm using Chrome 47.0.2526.58 beta (64-bit).

Also, my number inputs use line-height:normal; to align the contained text / numbers.

Most of the time, the content is cut off, because it is shifted down a few pixels.
This behaviour is affected by hover and active state of the input.

It's probably best described by this animated gif:

[image]

How can I fix this Chrome bug?

Comment: Have you tried to decrease your font-size?

Answer (score 0):

Input fields normally adjust to their font-size. 
If you have set a fixed height to your input field, that might cause the trouble.

Here's an example:

```css
input[type=text] {
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Also keep in mind that you're using a Beta version of your browser. If this problem is indeed browser related there's a change that it will be fixed in the next update.

It might be useful to fill in a bug-report for Google Chrome.